# How can i reset the cooldown of discord slash commands?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.tree.command(name="command", description="xxxxx")
@discord.app_commands.checks.cooldown(1, 3600, key=lambda i: (i.channel_id,i.user.id))
async def command(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    if interaction.channel.id != 1145817930429378661:
        
        embed = discord.Embed(colour=0xe5ff00,
                              timestamp=datetime.datetime.now(),
                              description=f"Please use <#1145817930429378661> for this command!")
        embed.set_footer(text="xxx",icon_url="xxx.png")
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed,ephemeral=True)
        
        return
    
    try:
        user = interaction.user.name
    except:
        user = "[ Unable to get name ]"

    print(f"{user} ran /command")
    


@client.tree.error
async def on_command_error(interaction:discord.Interaction,error:discord.app_commands.AppCommandError):
    if isinstance(error,discord.app_commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        cooldown = round(error.retry_after/60)
        time = "minutes"
        if cooldown > 60:
            cooldown = round(cooldown / 60)
            time = "hours"
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"You are currently on cooldown, you can reuse this command in {cooldown} {time}!",ephemeral=True)
    else:
        print(error)
        await interaction.response.send_message("There was an error, please retry the command! :slight_smile:",ephemeral=True)
```

This is my current code, I'm struggling trying to reset the cooldown if there is a command error or if its in the wrong channel.
Right now, if the user does the command in the wrong channel it will redirect them to the correct channel however, they have cooldown on the command in the wrong channel, obviously this isn't a major issue as it is the wrong channel but it's something i'd like to fix.
I'd like to also reset the cooldown if there was an command error (e.g. 'The application did not respond')

I've tried using .reset() on many different things with no success. If anyone can help, i'll forever be thankful

Comment: As far as I can see based on the documention, `on_command_error` gets called for every command error in your bot, no matter the channel. You need to filter for that using the `discord.Interaction` class you get as an argument (it has a `channel` member, access it via `interaction.channel`, like you do in your command function). You reset the cooldown, by calling the `reset()` function on the `discord.app_commands.Cooldown` class, the object of which would be accessed via `error.cooldown` in your code, so `error.cooldown.reset()` in total.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the discord slash command cooldown is **currently not possible**.

However, you can use the **decorator** `@app_commands.checks.dynamic_cooldown` to create a cooldown for users, that don't meet your if checks.

First of all, you need to **create a new function** that is **not async** to use it inside a new decorator:

```py
def cooldown_for_users(interaction: discord.Interaction) -> Optional[app_commands.Cooldown]:
    if interaction.channel.id != 1145817930429378661:
        return None
    return app_commands.Cooldown(1, 3600)
```

after that, you can use the new `@app_commands.checks.dynamic_cooldown` **decorator** on your command:

```py
@client.tree.command(name="command", description="xxxxx")
@app_commands.checks.dynamic_cooldown(cooldown_for_users, key=lambda i: (i.channel_id,i.user.id))
async def command(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    # ...
```

---

You can check out the **official Discord.py Documentation** for more information about this feature: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.checks.dynamic_cooldown

Comment: unrelated to the resetting cooldown issue, but in the past I tried using dynamic cooldowns to give different roles different cooldowns for example booster vs standard using a function, how ever I got an error everytime related to the type of the data I was returning, I may have just been formatting it wrong but do you possibly have any ideas of what I was doing wrong?

Comment: Please open a new thread regarding this error on Stackoverflow, sadly it's not allowed to ask multiple questions at once. But I will directly look into it then.

And if my answer helps you out, feel free to accept the answer. :)